Limit of integral of sum of cosine functions by CLT?
I want to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (2\pi)^{-d}n^{d/2}d^{-2n}\int_{[-\pi, \pi]^d} (\cos(x_1)+\cdots +\cos(x_d))^{2n} dx_1\cdots dx_d =2(d/4\pi)^{d/2}$$ holds.
How do I prove this?
It seems that the central limit theorem can be used for this problem, but I don't know how to apply it. Or is there another good way to prove it?

Hint: if $X\sim U(-\pi,,\pi)$ then $\Bbb E\cos X=0,,\Bbb E\cos^2X=\frac12$, so your sum of cosines $\approx N(0,,\frac12d)$. Since this approximation works best for large $d$, you need to justify a Normal approximation being good for high-order moments even for small $d$.

@J.G. Thank you so much!Your method would work well.

By symmetry, rewrite the integral as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{n})^d}{\pi^dd^{2n}}\int_{[0,\pi]^d}\mathrm{d}^d\mathbf{x}\left(\cos(x_1)+\cdots+\cos(x_d)\right)^{2n}$$
$$ = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{n})^d}{\pi^d}\int_{[0,\pi]^d}\mathrm{d}^d\mathbf{x}\left(\frac{\cos(x_1)+\cdots+\cos(x_d)}{d}\right)^{2n}$$
use the substitution $\sqrt{n}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}$
$$ = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi^d}\int_{[0,\pi\sqrt{n}]^d}\mathrm{d}^d\mathbf{y}\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)+\cdots+\cos\left(\frac{y_d}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{d}\right)^{2n}$$
For reasons that will become very obvious shortly, if we imagine the original hypercube $[0,\pi]^d$ split into $2^d$ subhypercubes at the $x_i=\frac{\pi}{2}$ hyperplanes, the integrals over any subhypercubes that don't contain the points $(0,\cdots,0)$ or $(\pi,\cdots, \pi)$ vanish in the limit. For now let's only focus on the subhypercube that contains $(0,\cdots,0)$. This integrand can be rewritten as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi^d}\int_{\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{n}\right]^d}\mathrm{d}^d\mathbf{y}\left(1-\frac{\mathbf{y}^2}{d(2n)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)^{2n} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\pi^d}\int_{[0,\infty)^d}\mathrm{d}^d\mathbf{y}\exp\left(-\frac{\mathbf{y}^2}{d}\right) = \frac{1}{\pi^d}\left(\frac{\sqrt{d\pi}}{2}\right)^d$$
or the product of $d$ Gaussian integrals. The $(\pi,\cdots,\pi)$ subhypercube will equal the same result since the $-1$ constant in the Taylor expansion will become a $+1$ due to the even exponent. All other subhypercubes fail to have a constant term that is greater than or equal to $1$, so their limits are dominated by the decaying exponential. Therefore our final answer is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi^d}\int_{[0,\pi\sqrt{n}]^d}\mathrm{d}^d\mathbf{y}\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)+\cdots+\cos\left(\frac{y_d}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{d}\right)^{2n}$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi^d}\left(\frac{\sqrt{d\pi}}{2}\right)^d + 0 + \cdots + 0 + \frac{1}{\pi^d}\left(\frac{\sqrt{d\pi}}{2}\right)^d = \boxed{2\left(\frac{d}{4\pi}\right)^{\frac{d}{2}}}$$

Very nice explanation!Thank you very much!
